# How to load a HTML String with relatives paths using the loadHtmlString method of the WebViewController

Tags: html, flutter, webview-flutter

I am trying to use a `WebViewWidget` on flutter to display a HTML content saved in a String.

I want to use a String instead of a file because the content could by modify several times and in this way I avoid to read and write the file constantly.

The HTML file have relative paths for the CSS files, images, videos, etc. and the `WebViewWidget` is not resolving them correctly.

The code is the following:

```
class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatPage({Key? key, required this.html}) : super(key: key);

  final DocumentModel html;

  @override
  State<ChatPage> createState() => ChatPageState();
}

lass ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  late final WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    String contet =
        File("${widget.html.directory}index.html").readAsStringSync();
        // We modify the file content here...

    content = '''<p>new content</p> 
                  <img src="./relative/path">
                  $content''';

    late final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params;
    params = const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();

    final WebViewController controller =
        WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params);

    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadHtmlString(content,
          baseURL: "${widget.html.directory}index.html");

    _controller = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
        title: Text(widget.html.title),
        elevation: 0.7,
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: _controller,
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried using several baseURLs but I can't figure out how is the correct way to implement it.

```
"file://path_to_file/"
"path_to_file/"
Uri.file("path_to_file/").toFilePath()
Uri.file("path_to_file/").toString()
Uri.directory("path_to_file/").toFilePath()
Uri.directory("path_to_file/").toString()
```

I generated the file path like `File("path_to_file/")`.path

I am using the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` method from the `file_provider` package and the files are storage in the app directory.

Can anyone tell me how I should use the baseURL so that the HTML relative paths are resolved correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Regards.

Comment: URLs in HTML need to be resolved relative to the origin URL for the page.  So you'll need to have a real or artificial base URL for that "string".

Comment: can you share an example? If the HTML file and all the sources (css, images, videos, etc) are in the same folder: `/app/HTAMLpage/` how can I implement the real or artificial base URL?